# I have unspent bitcoin in the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, private-key, multibit

I made a transaction from a multibit wallet. It arrived in the blockchain and was confirmed thousands of times. However, the transaction is set to 'unspent'.

Can I retreive this from the blockchain when I have the private key of multibit, or is it lost?

This is the transaction:
https://blockchain.info/tx-index/b2a861b053125b5be9e7ba1b88e655b0e1184973038e3a528b8deb446336ec24

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: this tx transfers funds to 1CUz94ynWJoor93wJG9PuVo3jtoJDGeahy and 
14UozGqkrb5RsE1MqQVP8i9va8nAsubc4V. If you have the private keys for these addresses, then you are ok. I see multibit is discontinued, so you might search a bit in the forum, and look here at their webpage: https://multibit.org/blog/2017/07/26/multibit-shutdown.html

Comment: It is not the transaction that is unspend, but rather bitcoins that belong to a certain wallet. Please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 2):

In short, bitcoin transactions are made up of inputs and outputs. When you sent funds, an input was spent, and the output went to the receiving bitcoin wallet. The unspent tag simply means that the funds that you sent have not yet been used as an input, and the funds are therefore still at the address to which you sent them.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't retrieve it.  You sent the transaction and it was confirmed, so the funds belong to the recipient now.  They have apparently chosen to leave them in that address without spending them so far, which is why the transaction is "unspent".  But the recipient is the only one who can spend those funds.